# Can I get an Intermediate Certificate to sign SSL Certificates for my own domain myself?

Tags: web-services, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

I am maintaining a project with quite a large server infrastructure.

At the moment I am using several SSL certificates for different subdomains, and that's not easy on the pocket.

A far more economical solution for me would be to get one wild card certificate and use it on all of my servers.

However those servers are spread across the globe, and if one of them gets compromised - physically or by any other means, the secret certificate key would fall into the hands of whoever gets into the system.

In that case, if I used a wild card certificate, the key compromised key would also be the key for all other components of the system (because they have the same certificate).

I do not want to compromise the SSL security of my main website because some unimportant edge server has been compromised.

That's why I wondered whether I can sign my own CSR for my own subdomains somehow.

Something like a "self service top level domain wide intermediate certificate authority"

Is there such a thing? As far as I understand certificate authorities and intermediate certificate authorities are not limited to specific scopes on their common name (domain).

However I know that for example Google on the fly generates certificates for security purposes on special parts of their website.

I wonder how they do that. Or are they a certificate authority on their own?

Hope the question is clear,
any help is appriciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if Google is a certificatation authority, I don't seem to find their CA.

Anyway, no Certification Authority should ever deliver a global intermediate CA. Some did and it lead to abuse, as expected. There is no way to deliver a intermediate CA limited to a CN, so no, there is no way to do what you are looking for.

It could be done by using DANE, though, but it will not be mainstream before many years. See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6698

Comment: thanks! +1 also for the alternative, i may look into it more closely for internal applications

Answer (score 1):

MPKI, Managed Public Key Infrastructure will give you the ability to create your own certs instantly on your pre-approved domains.

I do not think this will save you any money but does allow you to do many of the items you requested.

Comment: sounds interesting. however this means just that the provider issues the certificate without need for further verification, and not that i can generate them myself, right?

Comment: The only way to generate them yourself is to become a [CA](https://www.cabforum.org)

Answer (score 1):

About Google: Google has an intermediate certificate issued by GeoTrust.